# li and img tags not playing niceley

Tags: html, css

I always have this problem and always come up with some hacky workaround.  Anyone help?

```
<ul>
 <li>hello</li>
</ul>

<img src = 'image.jpg' />
```

so these are lined up next to each other in a row format.  When I try and push the list element down using margin-top: 1em nothing happens.  But when I do the margin-top: 1em on the ul tag it moves both the image and li tags down together.  How do I fix this? And Why does this happen?

JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/MZhAv/

if you change the margin-top on the li tag you will see it wont move.  I dont understand why that is.

Comment: can you create a JSfiddle on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Do you mean `<img src="image.jpg" />` rather than `<img>image.jpg</img>`?

Comment: Or maybe <a><img ... ></a> ?????

Comment: Ya my bad guys.  I through up a jsfiddle.

Comment: What behavior, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Perhaps `vertical-align: top;` is what you're looking for?...

Comment: I want to make HELLO even with the cats head. --Referencing the JSfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove the `display:inline` for the `il` to have the `margin-top` effect for both image and ul.
- If you want the image and the ul to be next to each other, with having the ul only `margin-top`, then check this link:

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3PmU/)

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
}

li {

        //border: 1px solid black;
        margin-left: 12em;
        margin-top: 2em;
        padding-top: 1em;
    }

img {
    float:left;

}
```

**Edit**

if you want the image on the right:
[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gqh35/)

HTML

```
<img src= "http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/magic-marker-icons-animals/114689-magic-marker-icon-animals-animal-cat1.png"/>
<ul>
    <li>HELLO</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
}

li {

        //border: 1px solid black;
        margin-left: 3em;
        margin-top: 2em;
        padding-top: 1em;
    }

img {
    float:left;

}
```

Comment: No this isn't quite right.  I would like the <li> tag to move separately from the cat.

Comment: @user2908778 did you check the demo ?

Comment: Yes it doesn't move independently when chnaging the margin-top on the li tag.

Comment: when you change the li margin-top, the cat image doesn't change :O

Comment: only if it is on the left side of it, not if it is on the right side.